# anton deitmar harmonic analysis exercise

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Let P be the group of upper triangular matrices in SL2(R).
The injection η : P → GL2(C) can be viewed as a representation on V =
C2. Show that η is not the sum of irreducible representations.

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: I look forward to telling others their comments